# Rust mutable/inmutable borrow error in closure

Tags: rust, ownership

I'm trying to abstract the initialisation of the `glium` crate but I'm having ownership problems. I've been looking the documentation and looks like it may be related to this rule:

> 1. At any given time, you can have either but not both of:
>
>    - One mutable reference.
>    - Any number of immutable references.

I think that I understand the rule, how it applies and why it exists, but I can't see what's happening with my code. I've created a cleaned-up example:

```
extern crate glium;

use glium::glutin;

pub struct Renderer {
    pub events_loop: glium::glutin::EventsLoop,
    pub display: glium::Display,
}

impl Renderer {
    pub fn new() -> Renderer {
        let events_loop = glutin::EventsLoop::new();
        let window = glutin::WindowBuilder::new();
        let context = glutin::ContextBuilder::new();
        let display = glium::Display::new(window, context, &events_loop).unwrap();

        Renderer {
            events_loop: events_loop,
            display: display,
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut renderer = Renderer::new();

    renderer.events_loop.poll_events(|event| {
        // Some event handling logic with `match`, somewhere I've this line:
        let window_size = renderer.display.gl_window().get_inner_size_pixels().unwrap();
    });
}
```

I get this error:

```
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `renderer` as immutable because `renderer.events_loop` is also borrowed as mutable
  --> src/main.rs:27:38
   |
27 |     renderer.events_loop.poll_events(|event| {
   |     --------------------             ^^^^^^^ immutable borrow occurs here
   |     |
   |     mutable borrow occurs here
28 |         // Some event handling logic with `match`, somewhere I've this line:
29 |         let window_size = renderer.display.gl_window().get_inner_size_pixels().unwrap();
   |                           -------- borrow occurs due to use of `renderer` in closure
30 |     });
   |      - mutable borrow ends here
```

If `renderer` is not mutable, I get this one:

```
error[E0596]: cannot borrow immutable field `renderer.events_loop` as mutable
  --> src/main.rs:27:5
   |
25 |     let renderer = Renderer::new();
   |         -------- consider changing this to `mut renderer`
26 |
27 |     renderer.events_loop.poll_events(|event| {
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ cannot mutably borrow immutable field
```

Comment: The duplicate's solution [applied to your code](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=94254124c3dc4a2523e3400498f1c376&version=stable).

Comment: Thanks! Btw, I saw your comment on the edit and learnt that VS Code errors don't tell all the story. Now I'm looking the errors on the console, really informative. :-)

Comment: I'd have hoped that VS Code applies the "underlining" and "highlighting" from the plain-text form in some graphical way, not just losing them completely... For my part, thanks for letting me know it's from VS Code; now I have one more idea why sometimes error messages are missing important detail!